# Thread doesn't get executed in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am trying to create a program in C to calculate the sum and the product via threads.It's my  exercise for university.The problem I face is that when I run the program the thread doesn't seem to execute.I am stuck and I don't know how to proceed.

```
  #include <pthread.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  int T1; //store the sum
  int *array; //global varriable

 void *Sum(void *N){ //function used by thread to calculate sum
     printf("I am the 1st thread i ll calculate the sum for you");
     long S=(long) N;
     int sum=0;
     int i;

     for (i=0; i<S; ++i){
       sum = sum +array[i];
     }  
     T1 = sum;
     pthread_exit(NULL);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  long N;
  printf("%d\n",T1);
  printf("give the size of the array please\n");
  scanf("%ld", &N);
  int *array= (int*) malloc((N)*sizeof(int)); // dynamic array
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<N; ++i)
  {
     array[i]=rand() % 301 + (-150);// creates random numbers from -150     to 150
  }
  for (i=0; i<N; ++i) {
    printf(" %d\n", array[i]);
  }

  pthread_t Th;
  pthread_create(&Th, NULL,Sum, (void*)N); //creates thread

  printf("%d\n",T1);
  return (0);
 }`
```

I tried changing `pthread_exit(NULL);` to `return(0)` or `return(T1)`
but it didn't work. I changed the Sum function to:

```
    void *Sum(void *N){ //function used by thread to calculate sum
      printf("I am the 1st thread i ll calculate the sum for you");
      pthread_exit(NULL);
   }
```

It didn't work either.the output I get anyway is :

```
0
give the size of the array please
2
 117
 113
0
```

Note that I get no compile errors or warnings.

Comment: You forgot to join your thread.

Comment: From `man pthread_join`: `pthread_join -- wait for thread termination`

Comment: the posted code has a few problems.  When compiling, always enable all the warnings (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` ) then fix those problems.  1) there is a 'stray' ' after the closing brace of the function `main()`.  2) the parameters for `main()` are not used, suggest `int main( void )`

Comment: In C, when calling `malloc()`, do not cast the returned value as that value type is already `void*` so can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting the returned value just clutters the code and makes debugging and/or maintaining the code that much harder.   Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: when calling `scanf()` (and family of functions) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  For this line: `scanf("%ld", &N);` any returned value but 1 means the operation failed.

Comment: before calling `rand()`, always call `srand(seed)` to create a random sequence.  Suggest: `#include <time.h>` and `srand( time(NULL) );`  Note: `srand()` should only be called once, so place that call before the loop

Comment: the `_` operator has a higher precedence than the `%` operator, so this line: `array[i]=rand() % 301 + (-150);`  should be similar to: `array[i]= -150 + (rand() % 301);`   I.E. use parens to get the desired sequence of operations

Comment: this line: `long S=(long) N;` has the problem that a void pointer should not be cast to a long int.  Suggest correcting this line:`pthread_create(&Th, NULL,Sum, (void*)N);` to: `pthread_create(&Th, NULL,Sum, (void*)&N);`  then correcting this line: `long S=(long) N;` to: `long S=(long) *N;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Your  main() thread is not waiting for the thread to complete. So your thread *Sum* may not get executed at all. Call [`pthread_join()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html):

```
pthread_create(&Th, NULL,Sum, &N); 
pthread_join(Th, 0); // waits for the thread "Sum"
```

2) You are declaring and assigning `array` *again* in `main()`. So the allocation is only for the `array` in `main()` since it [*shadows*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the global variable. This leads to [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as the `array` you write into in `Sum` thread wasn't allocated any memory. So

```
  int *array= (int*) malloc((N)*sizeof(int)); // dynamic array
```

should be

```
  array= malloc((N)*sizeof(int));
```

A `void*` can be converted to any other object pointer automatically. So the cast is unnecessary and potentially [dangerous](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html).

3) Integer to pointer conversion has *implementation defined* behaviour. So I would avoid it. Since the thread only reads `N`, you can pass the address of it:

```
pthread_create(&Th, NULL,Sum, &N); //creates thread
```

and in the thread function do:

```
  long S=*((long*) N);
```

Comment: Thank you!!  I changed the array allocation and solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
pthread_create(&Th, NULL,Sum, (void*)N); //creates thread
```

After this line you need to to either join or detach the thread. In this case you'll want to join the thread or your program will end right away.

```
pthread_join(Th, NULL);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.when i use `pthread_join(Th, NULL); `i get a Segmentation fault.Any suggestions why?